# SmsRetrieverHelper Timed out waiting for SMS , Flutter Firebase auto fill sms verification not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to verify phone via sms verification

Actually everything is working,
verification msg is coming but not verified automatically or auto fill automatically.

That auto fill sms is just a problem
Attaching a picture of the error as well as well.[image]

Thanks

```
verifyPhone() async {
currentUser.value.verificationId = '';
smsSent = '';
final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {};
final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResent]) {
  currentUser.value.verificationId = verId;
};
final PhoneVerificationCompleted _verifiedSuccess =
    (AuthCredential auth) {};
final PhoneVerificationFailed _verifyFailed = (FirebaseAuthException e) {};
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: widget.user.phone,
  timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
  verificationCompleted: _verifiedSuccess,
  verificationFailed: _verifyFailed,
  codeSent: smsCodeSent,
  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
);
```

}

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              // height: 70,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                  codeLength: 6,
                  decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                    bgColorBuilder:
                        FixedColorBuilder(Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1)),
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    colorBuilder:
                        FixedColorBuilder(Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1)),
                  ),
                  currentCode: smsSent,
                  onCodeSubmitted: (code) {
                    setState(() {
                      smsSent = code;
                    });
                    
                  },
                  onCodeChanged: (code) {
                    setState(() {
                      smsSent = code;
                    });
                    
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this into **PhoneVerificationCompleted** Method

```
FirebaseAuth? auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

await auth!.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: //,
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: //,
      codeSent: //,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: //,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
      // forceResendingToken: 30,
    );

     verificationComplete
          (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await auth!.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) async {
          if (value.user != null) {
            log("Done !!", name: "verificationCompleted");
          } else {
            log("Failed!!", name: "verificationCompleted");
          }
        }).catchError((e) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Something Went Wrong: ${e.toString()}');
        });
      };
```